# How to draw border around rounded imageview?

Tags: android

I need to draw a red border around an `ImageView` using this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float radius = 45.0f;
    Paint bp= new Paint();
    bp.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bp.setColor(Color.RED);
    bp.setStrokeWidth(16);


    Path clipPath = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, bp);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

But it doesn't seem to draw the border?  And I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Can any one please help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you see and what you are trying to achieve? because this is what I see :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/NxadM.png

Comment: I have posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is what I ended up doing in the end:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

private static final int PADDING = 8;
private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 16f;

private Paint mBorderPaint;

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initBorderPaint();
}

private void initBorderPaint() {
    mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(PADDING, PADDING, getWidth() - PADDING, getHeight() - PADDING, mBorderPaint);
}
}
```

It doesn't give the rounded corners as wanted,  but not really necessary.   This just creates a border around the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a xml in drawable folder naming border.xml and add this code :

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="0.7dip" android:color="#808080"/>
    </shape>
   ```
2. Now add this to your frame layout and put your imageview inside frame layout and you are done.

   ```
   <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/border"
   android:padding="3dp" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="110dp"
     android:layout_margin="1dp"     />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Hope it helps.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a xml in drawable folder naming border.xml and to it add this code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
   <size android:height="100dp" android:width="100dp"/>
   <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
   <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="#f2db2f"/>
   </shape>
   ```
2. And in your layout add this:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:foregroundGravity="center|top"
   android:foreground="@drawable/border"
   android:layout_weight="4">
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/dog"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:src="@drawable/gears"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```